# Insertion sort in Assembly

Tags: sorting, assembly, masm, insertion-sort, irvine32

So I'm coding out an insertion sort (in assembly) based on this high level code:

```
void insertionSort(int data[ ], int arraySize) {
        int insert;
        int moveItem;
        for(int next=1; next<arraySize; next++) {
                    insert=data[next];  //store the value in the current element
                    moveItem=next;    //initialize location to place element

                    while((moveItem>0)&&(data[moveItem-1]>insert)) {
                               //shift element one slot to the right
                                data[moveItem]=data[moveItem-1];
                                moveItem--;
                    }  //end while

                    data[moveItem]=insert;
        } //end for
} //end insertionSort
```

There are exactly 20 random numbers in an array called myArray. I cannot use an of the decision derivatives that come in the library that comes with our book. So basically movs, cmps, loops, and jumps
Here's what I got. I had it sorting the first of 20 random numbers earlier, but I've confused myself to death and have no idea what I'm doing any more. It crashes when it gets to the insertion sort method. Help please.

```
TITLE Insertion Sort (main.asm)
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data

elems = 20

myArray  sdword   elems dup(0)
str1 byte "Press enter" ,0
str2 byte "The array now is ",0
next sdword 1
start sdword ?

.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr
    call CreateRandom
    call Display
    call InsertionSort
    call Display
    exit
main ENDP

CreateRandom PROC
;;;;Creates 20 random numbers and populates myArray;;;;;
    call Randomize
    mov ecx, 20
    mov edx, OFFSET myArray

L1:                     
    call Random32                   ;create random number
    mov [edx], eax                  ; move random number to the appropriate spot in the array
    add edx, 4                      ; increase the address of what it is pointing to
    loop L1
    mov edx, OFFSET str1            ; "press enter to continue"
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    call Crlf
    ret
CreateRandom ENDP

Display PROC
;;;; Displays current form of the array myArray;;;;;
    mov edx, OFFSET str2                ; "The array now is:"
    call WriteString                    ; write string
    call Crlf
    mov esi, OFFSET myArray             ; offset of the array 
    mov ecx, 20                         ; index of the loop
L2:  
    mov eax, [esi]                      ; move array at that point to eax
    call WriteDec                       ; print out the array as a decimal
    call Crlf                           ; next line
    add esi, 4                          ; next element in the array
    loop L2
    call Crlf
    ret
Display ENDP

InsertionSort PROC
mov ecx, 19
mov edx, OFFSET myArray
mov ebx, OFFSET myArray            ; eax=next
add ebx, 4                        ;moves up the array to second element comparable to next

outterloop:
    mov    esi, [ebx]                    ; esi=data[next]
    mov eax, ebx                ;movelterm=ebx
    L1:
        mov edx, [eax-4]            ;move the number that is greater into edx
        mov [eax], edx                ;move the number into that 2nd element of the
        sub eax, 4
        mov esi, [eax]
        cmp eax, [edx]
        JNG endinner                        ; if the address is not greater than the first address, skip to the end
        mov edx, [eax-4]
        cmp edx, esi                        ; if the address is greater, than it already sorted, skip to end
        JG endinner
        loop L1
    endinner:
        mov [eax], esi  ; move first to the second to finish the sort
        add ebx, 4    ;move to the next element of the array
    inc next   ;counting outside loop
        cmp ecx, next
        JNE outterloop ;return to top of for loop

ret
InsertionSort ENDP

END main
```

Comment: A brave soul is the one who goes "Here's 171 lines of assembler, what's wrong?" :-) Just sayin'...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't examined your code in detail, but I notice that `InsertionSort` seems to be using `edx` for two different purposes at once: as a pointer into the array, and to hold one of the values from the array. This will certainly break even if nothing else is wrong.

So, at the start of `InsertionSort` you say `mov edx, OFFSET myArray` -- it's a pointer into the array. Then, a few lines later, `mov edx, [eax-4]` -- oops, no, it's a value from the array. And a few lines later again, `cmp eax, [edx]` -- oh, no, now it's a pointer into the array again.

Perhaps that last instruction should be `cmp edx, [eax]` or something? Because `eax` does seem to be a pointer into the array here.

Comment: I have fixed what you have mentioned, but it does not fix my problem. I have also tried using [eax] in a cmp, and it seems to throw an error. Also, there are two registers that start out with the offset of that array, but I need the offset to double check later on that I have not left the bounds of that array. Looks a little more like this now:   I

    L6:
  cmp esp, esi      
  JG endinner
        mov ebp, [eax-4]            
        mov [eax], ebp              
        sub eax, 4
  cmp eax, edx
  JNG endinner      
  mov esp, [eax-4]

  loop L6

Comment: I don't think it's feasible to debug your code given only the information that it "looks a little more like this"! Could you please update the code in the question to reflect whatever fixes you've made?

Comment: (But it sounds as if you're using `esp` before you've actually set it.)

Comment: Also, if I'm correctly understanding what's meant to be in `esp`, I think your comparison immediately after `L6` is the wrong way around.